# Finding an Excel Print Preview dialog from C# which allows user to change printer

Tags: c#, excel, printing, print-preview

I am doing Office automation from a C# application to Excel.  I am trying to bring up a print preview dialog (or a print dialog with a preview option).  I also want the user to have the ability to select a different print than the default one.

I have tried

```
sheet1.PrintPreview();
```

and

```
sheet1.PrintOutEx(1, 1, 1, true);
```

but I don't see a way for the user to select a different printer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a built-in dialog for your Windows application. If you have a reference to the Excel automation `Application` object, you will be able to call up pretty much any built-in dialog that is available in Excel.

2 links that you might find helpful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.dialogs.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlbuiltindialog.aspx

Example: in order to pull up the print preview dialog, you would do this:

```
var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
bool dialogResult =    
    excelApp.Dialogs[Excel.XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogPrintPreview].Show(
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: +1 Although in .Net 4/4.5 you don't need any of the type.missings, because they are all optional. `excelApp.Dialogs[Excel.XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogPrintPreview].Show();` works just as well.

Comment: @code4life: Yes that gives a print preview, but how does the user change the printer?

Comment: @MikeC, I would recommend that you try either `xlDialogPrint` or `xlDialogPrinterSetup` instead of `xlDialogPrintPreview`. If these built-in dialogs don't fit your needs, you will have to make your own custom dialog...

Comment: @code4life: Boy, those XlBuildInDialog dialogs really look old, like Windows 2000 or NT.  I am surprised that there is not a dialog, old or new, that lets you see a print preview before printing as well as allowing the user to change the printer (all in the same dialog).

Answer (score 1):

You change the default printer of the Application object, and then print the worksheet, like so. You can get the printers installed on the computer from `System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters` and then display these to the user in some sort of dialogue, and then set the `ActivePrinter` of the Excel Application instance like so, and then display the Print Preview Dialogue:

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Add();
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets[1];

var printers = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters;

Console.WriteLine("Select printer (type the number):");
Console.WriteLine();

for (int i = 0; i < printers.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", i, printers[i]);
}

int selection = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

application.ActivePrinter = printers[selection];
worksheet.PrintPreview();
```

Comment: Thanks JMK, I could use that to build a dialog for my Windows app, but is there a built in dialog for Windows that could be used?

Comment: What sort of application are you writing? Console/Windows Form/WPF?